# NSPredicate Returns No Results with Fetch Request, Works with Array Filtering

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

My situation is simple: I have some records in my core data store. One of their attributes is a string called "localId". There's a point where I'd like to find the record with a particular localId value. The obvious way to do this is with an NSFetchRequest and an NSPredicate. However, when I set this up, the request returns zero records.

If, however, I use the fetch request without the predicate, returning all records, and just loop over them looking for the target localId value, I do find the record I'm looking for. In other words, the record is there, but the fetch request can't find it.

My other methods in which I use fetch requests and predicates are all working as expected. I don't know why this one is failing.

I want to do this:

```
- (void)deleteResultWithLocalID:(NSString *)localId {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WCAAssessmentResult" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localId == %@", localId]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSAssert(error == nil, ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error]));
    if ([results count]) [context deleteObject:[results objectAtIndex:0]];
    else NSLog(@"could not find record with localID %@", localId);
    [self saveContext];
}
```

But I end up having to do this:

```
- (void)deleteResultWithLocalID:(NSString *)localId {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WCAAssessmentResult" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSAssert(error == nil, ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error]));
    for (WCAAssessmentResult *result in results) {
        if ([result.localId isEqualToString:localId]) {
            NSLog(@"result found, deleted");
            [context deleteObject:result];
        }
    }
    [self saveContext];
}
```

Any clues as to what could be going wrong?

**edit**

I've found that I can use the predicate I'm creating to get the results I expect after the fetch request has been executed. So, the following also works:

```
- (WCAChecklistItem *)checklistItemWithId:(NSNumber *)itemId {
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WCAChecklistItem" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
     NSArray *foundRecords = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
     foundRecords = [foundRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"serverId == %@", itemId]];
     if ([foundRecords count]) {
         return [foundRecords objectAtIndex:0];
     } else {
         NSLog(@"can't find checklist item with id %@", itemId);
         return nil;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've come across someone else experiencing this very issue:

http://markmail.org/message/7zbcxlaqcgtttqo4

He hasn't found a solution either.

Blimey! I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to say it but the most common cause of these types of problems is simple typos. Make sure that your attribute names and the predicate are the same. Make sure that your property names and the attributes names are the same. If a reference to a property works but a reference to attribute name doesn't there is probably a mismatch.

You could test for the latter by comparing the return of:

```
[result valueForKey:@"localID"]
```

... with the return of:

```
result.localID
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll go through and make sure that I've got things spelled correctly. This issue is happening across several attributes, however, so I'm inclined to think it's something more fundamental. Hopefully I'm wrong! Wil report back. Thanks again.

Comment: You know, this can't be the problem, because as I say in my question I am able to filter the results afterwards using the same predicate I'm attempting to use in the fetch request. So the predicate itself can't be the problem, at least not in terms of spelling. Why would a predicate be valid for filtering the results array but not the fetch request?

Comment: The code above doesn't show the exact same predicate. Moreover, if you have NSManagedObject subclasses defined, you can create a property name that does not agree with the entity property name. A fetch will look for the entity property name while a predicate on the array will look at the class property name.

Comment: I've seen this a lot in both my own code and others. Failed simple predicates are almost always the result of typos somewhere.

Comment: I still don't comprehend how a typo could cause this particular behavior, where the predicate fails with the fetch request but works fine to filter the results of a fetch request.

Comment: A fetch request does not work on object but rather on the store. That means it looks for the entity key names and not the property name of the class. An array predicate by contrast does look at the property names. In any case, this is a very simple, almost the simplest predicate possible. If it is failing, then the cause is likely something very simple and not some arcane bug. However, simple doesn't mean "easy to track down."

Comment: I might recommend you get someone else to have a look at your code and track the keynames. I had a similar error last year and it took me two days to find a one letter typo just because I'd looked at the code so much I began to see what I expected to see.

Comment: Thanks, Tech! I'll investigate this thoroughly soon and report back. I'm hopeful that it is indeed a typo.

Comment: @CharlieMezak did you ever figure out what the problem was? I am having the same issue as you and I cannot for the life of me get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 4):

If `localId` is a numerical value, then you should use an `NSNumber` object in the predicate formation instead of an `NSString`.

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localId == %@", 
    [NSNumber numberWithString:localId]]];
```

`NSPredicate` format strings automatically quote NSString objects.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point, but localId is a string value. So I don't think that's the issue. I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: And now it seems the problem is common to all of my predicated fetch requests, both for string and numerical values! AArrg!