# FetchRequest with NSPredicate not finding results?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am storing data in a table that has the columns "name" and "series". I am using this NSPredicate to query:

```
var request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entry")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ AND series = %@", name, series)
return request
```

The 'name' and 'series' variables are passed in as String arguments, which are also the data types on the table.

For some reason, this query returns no data. If I do a fetch request on this table without specifying a predicate I can see that the data is indeed there. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

For what it's worth I have tried enclosing the conditionals in parens but that didn't seem to make a difference either. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I've tried many different things but so far nothing is working. I'm really stumped.

For what it's worth it seems like I am having the same issue as this person: [NSPredicate Returns No Results with Fetch Request, Works with Array Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405897/nspredicate-returns-no-results-with-fetch-request-works-with-array-filtering)

But, there isn't anything on that entry stating specifically what the solution to the problem was.

Comment: The strings are exact matches? Including capitalisation and white space? Are you really looking for an exact match or a partial match with case leniency?

Comment: It's an exact match and all the data is controlled by the app, there is no user input.

Comment: You'll need to show more info about the model, request and sample data. Presumably no error from the fetch?

Comment: Try to create a predicate only with `name` or `series`. May be it will help to localize a bug.

Comment: There are some ways t which can help you to debug your queries: the first is debugging/tracking the queries executed against the underlying sqlLite db using the Xcode flag   [http://waynehartman.com/posts/how-to-enable-sql-tracingdebugging-for-core-data-in-xcode.html](`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`).  The second is to see what data exactly are contained in the db using [https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor](Core Data editor)

Comment: @lucky_starss that is a great resource! I am trying it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh wow...thank you everyone so much for all your answers. In the end it turned out that when I was populating the id for inserting a new row into the table, I was looking at a different table to calculate the new primary key id.

So I was overwriting existing records, which is why my query kept failing.

Kids, if you copy/paste your code without rigorously checking it, you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the data is there by

1. printing the URL of the application documents directory to the console.
2. going to this directory in Terminal
3. running `sqlite3 <databaseName>`
4. trying `select * from z<entityName>  where name = '<nameData>'`

You will be able to explore the data and check if it contains what you expect. Don't forget to also check the content of your `name` and `series` variables in the code.

Comment: I went to the database...and all the data was there. I turned on SQL debug tracing and ran the same query that core data is running...it finds the record no problem. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Did you check the variables? Could you perhaps post the values of your variables to your question and report the results of the comparison with the actually database content?

Comment: I checked them and as far as I can tell they are *exactly* the same. Unless there are extra characters in there that I can't see (whitespace?) I'm really at a loss. I ran my select query and typed in the names exactly. Maybe I'm blind to the difference at this point because I've been staring at it for so long.